# What does @ signify in a query expression?

Tags: postgresql, syntax, operator

What does the @ symbol signify in this sql expression?

```
update some_table set some_number=(@some_number+1) where some_id=1;
```

It seems to return the same result as:

```
update some_table set some_number=some_number+1 where some_id=1;
```

Comment: Please tag your post. It is unclear which SQL language you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` is the ["absolute value" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html).

```
SELECT @ -1;
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

It returns the same value for positive numbers.